# Query in SQLite with variable and sort by Month as parameter

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, select, sql-order-by

I need a report with Firstname, Lastname, and TotalAmount, for all orders for a specified month. The report should be sorted so that the customer that spend the most money is on the top.

I am able to query the list in DESC but how can the user input a variable and then create a case for ech month? My code works with the month hard-coded.

Table Orders:

```
cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Orders`;")
cursor.execute('''
CREATE TABLE `Orders` (
  `OrderID` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  `OrderDate` VARCHAR(11) NULL,
  `CustId` INT NULL,
  `TotalAmount` DOUBLE NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (`CustId`) REFERENCES Customers(`CustID`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
''')
```

Table Customers:

```
cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Customers`;")
cursor.execute('''
CREATE TABLE `Customers` (
  `CustID` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  `FirstName` VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
  `LastName` VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
  `City` TEXT NULL,
  `Country` TEXT NULL,
  `Phone` VARCHAR(15) NULL
);
''')
```

I wrote this

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
for row in cursor.execute('''SELECT Firstname, Lastname, orders.TotalAmount
                            FROM customers
                            INNER JOIN orders on orders.CustID = customers.CustID
                            WHERE  orderDate like '%02-2020'
                            GROUP BY customers.custid, customers.firstname, customers.lastname
                           ORDER BY TotalAmount desc;'''):

                          print(row)
cursor.close()
```

Do I have to ask the user which month they want to see the customer spent more money, store it in a variable and then do the query? or?

Conceptually I was thinking about this:

- Ask for which month the report is needed
- Store that variable in a variable and produce a if case like:

`(if variable = 0 OR variable > 12)
 then (Error that is not a month)
 elseif variable = 1 then "WHERE  orderDate like '%01-2020'"
 elseif variable = 2 then "WHERE  orderDate like '%02-2020'"
 elseif variable = 3 then "WHERE  orderDate like '%03-2020'"`

Not sure is the best approach.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Stop trying to code your overall goal & explain what you expected instead from the given code & why.

Comment: Was not my intention to be, sorry for that. I ll be going through your suggestion and try to make a better question. I have written all the code I had done by myself, If I am here is for suggestion and to learn more. In this case I dont know how to "ask user for variable", store it and then print the cases. So I am asking people if I amin right direction or not and if they have suggestions...

Comment: How can we possibly know the answer to "Do I have to ask the user"? Or what interface the user supposed to communicate through? You need to tell us. What was the exact task that you were given? When you know exactly what needs to be done, research how to do it & ask 1 clear question the 1st place you get stuck. Please clarify via edits, not comments. Asking for "suggestions" is not an on-topic question. [help] Good luck. PS For multi-line code use code blocks not back ticks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQLite, you could just use string functions. Say you want the report for the month of may 2020, you could add the following `where` clause to your query:

```
where orderDate like '%05-2020'
```

Note: I suspect that your query should make use of aggregation, so all orders of each customer are grouped together in a single record:

```
select c.firstname, c.lastname, sum(o.totalamount) monthamount
from customers c
inner join orders o on o.custid = c.custid
where orderDate like '%05-2020'
group by c.custid, c.firstname, c.lastname
order by monthamount desc
```

Comment: ok thank you. I was thinking to ask to the user for which month he wants the report, store it in a variable...and then create a switch case query for each month. Or is a bed idea?

Comment: @gigi: you can use a query parameter to pass the variable to your query. There is no need for a `case` expression as far as I see.

Comment: I understand the logic to pass a paramenter, (even I am not sure how to do that) but I dont understand how to deal with the date since is in fomrat DD-MM-YYY. I addedd a pic.